# Ошибка синтаксиса ms['Close', '2016-01-01':'2016-12-31'].plot()

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Пытаюсь задать два аргумента графику, но jupiter ругается на ошибку синтаксиса и принимает только один аргумент, либо столбец close либо срез строк с датами. В переменной ms, csv таблица, где есть цены в столбцах, один из которых close и строки с датами. Как мне вывести цену за определенный период и задать два аргумента?

Comment: Может в обратном порядке попробовать и через `loc`:`ms.loc['2016-01-01':'2016-12-31', 'Close'].plot()`. Но вообще лучше бы вы привели свои данные в воспроизводимом виде.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `.loc` и первым аргументом должен быть индекс, а вторым название столбца. Воспроизводимый пример:

```py
import pandas as pd

ms = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2016-01-01','2016-06-30','2016-12-31'], 'Close': [1, 2, 3]})
ms['date'] = pd.to_datetime(ms['date'])
ms = ms.set_index('date')
ms.loc['2016-01-01':'2016-12-31', 'Close'].plot()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! Заработало)